# Conditional formatting in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done conditional formatting using jquery in a HTML table. It is working fine on the 1st page of datatable, but from the 2nd page, it is not working. I am using this code:

```
   $("table.dataTable td:nth-child(6)").each(function () {

                if (parseInt($(this).text(), 10) > 0) {

                    $(this).parent("tr").css("background-color", "#baf2ef");
                    $('tr').each(function () {
                        var tds = $(this).find('td');
                        var len = tds.length;

                        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            $(tds[i]).css('text-align', 'center');
                            // $(tds[i]).css('white-space', 'nowrap');
                        }
                    });
                }

                else {

                    $('tr').each(function () {
                        var tds = $(this).find('td');
                        var len = tds.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            $(tds[i]).css('text-align', 'center');
                            // $(tds[i]).css('white-space', 'nowrap');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Please help.

Comment: is the problem with the row background color?

Comment: I think you have to call your code each time, the page is changed.

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui yes.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ How can call this? I use bootstrap datatable which has the pagination property

Comment: @All I need it ..Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do your js function on the page event of your datatable.

```
$('table.dataTable').on('page.dt', function () {
    //your code here
});
```

This has not been tested and you may have to deal with a problem : the code might be executed before the pager has loaded the content.

Let me know,